# pandas, dropping empty column

Tags: pandas

How do I check if there is a column filled with only 'None' values?
How do I drop that column?

So something similar to:

```
If column in dataframe is None:
    drop column
```

Here's a dummy data example where the solution should identify the 5th column as empty and drop that column:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# dictionary of lists
dict = {'First Score':[100, np.nan, np.nan, 95],
        'Second Score': [30, np.nan, 45, 56],
        'Third Score':[52, np.nan, 80, 98],
        'Fourth Score':[60, 67, 68, 65],
        'Fifth Score':[ np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan,  np.nan]
        }

# creating a dataframe from dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), None)
```

Comment: Also pls don't assign anything to `dict` function

Comment: I wouldn't dream of it, only used in example for clarity, thanks

Comment: @HenryEcker the answer given is more eloquent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
df_out = df.dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  First Score Second Score Third Score  Fourth Score
0       100.0         30.0        52.0            60
1        None         None        None            67
2        None         45.0        80.0            68
3        95.0         56.0        98.0            65
```

Per docs, [pd.DataFrame.dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html#pandas-dataframe-dropna) has parameter 'how' which we can set to 'all'.